# MongoDB run query from terminal

Tags: bash, mongodb, terminal

I'm try run bash script from terminal (Ubuntu 14.04), but i'm get error:

```
$ ../scripts/for_webapp/init_devices_limit.sh 
db.company.update({"_id": NumberInt(777)}, {$set: {"devices_limit": NumberInt(-1)}}, {"multi":true});
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.5
connecting to: localhost:27017/statistic
2016-04-22T12:37:01.366+0500 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script @(shell eval):1:25
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

: ${DBHOST:=localhost}
: ${DBPORT:=27017}
: ${DBNAME:=statistic}

: ${COMPANY_ID:=777}
: ${INIT_VALUE:=-1}

QUERY='db.company.update({"_id": NumberInt('$COMPANY_ID')}, {$set: {"devices_limit": NumberInt('$INIT_VALUE')}}, {"multi":true});'
echo $QUERY

mongo $DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBNAME --eval $QUERY
```

Comment: The problem is with the use of quotes in your query string. What is acceptable to unix need not necessarily be acceptable javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solve this with using *EOF* input signal (without use --eval argument).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

: ${DBHOST:=localhost}
: ${DBPORT:=27017}
: ${DBNAME:=statistic}

: ${COMPANY_ID:=777}
: ${INIT_VALUE:=-1}

QUERY='db.company.update({"_id": NumberInt('$COMPANY_ID')}, {$set: {"devices_limit": NumberInt('$INIT_VALUE')}})'
echo $QUERY

# mongo $DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBNAME --eval $QUERY

# don't use --eval
mongo $DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBNAME <<_EOF_
$QUERY
_EOF_
```